git force push to upstream remote branch of PR
I'm trying to write a shell alias to force push to a contributor's branch on a PR that is currently checked out on my local machine.
I believe the command that needs to be generated is:
git push REMOTE LOCAL_BRANCH:REMOTE_BRANCH --force

The best I can come up with uses git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{u} to get REMOTE/REMOTE_BRANCH, and then cuts it up to generate the push command:
alias forcepr="git push $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{u} | cut -d'/' -f1) $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD):$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{u} | cut -d'/' -f2-) --force"

Is there a better (shorter) way?
I have searched for similar questions, and all I found was general questions about the syntax of force push, or advice about the dangers of force push and when it may be warranted. This question is specifically about how to force push to the upstream branch that is already tracked from the local branch (e.g. after pulling with GitHub desktop).
Thanks!

If you are using GitHub and you check out the PR using the gh cli (gh pr checkout 123), then everything is already set up so that you can just git push (or git push -f) without any additional configuration.

Wow, I'm so used to git push origin main that I completely forgot about the simple syntax! Thanks. Please add this as an answer.

I've added an answer, along with a little more detail.

Option 1: Change the default push behavior
git config push.default upstream

Then you can simply use git push to push to the tracked upstream.
Thanks to @jthill for this solution.

Option 2: Create a shell function
The alias in the question makes the mistake of evaluating rev-parse when the shell script is interpreted, not when the command is run. This causes it to always push to whichever branch is checked out when the shell loads. Instead, this can be written as a function, which has the benefit of eliminating the duplicate rev-parse calls:
# push to the current branch's upstream
pushpr() {
  remote_fullname=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{u})
  remote=$(echo $remote_fullname | cut -d'/' -f1)
  remote_branch=$(echo $remote_fullname | cut -d'/' -f2-)
  git push $remote HEAD:$remote_branch "$@"
}


If you are using GitHub and you check out the PR using the gh cli (gh pr checkout 123), then everything is already set up so that you can just git push (or git push -f) without any additional configuration.
E.g., if I have a local copy of the moby repository and I check out PR 480403:
gh pr checkout 48403

I end up with the following configuration in .git/config:
[branch "test_registry_v3"]
        remote = git@github.com:thaJeztah/docker.git
        pushRemote = git@github.com:thaJeztah/docker.git
        merge = refs/heads/test_registry_v3

If I had appropriate permissions (I do not), this configures things so that simply running git push while on this branch will push changes to the right place.
That demonstrates how you could configure this yourself if you weren't using GitHub (or you weren't using the gh cli).

I just tried this out, and I get this error:
`fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
the name of your current branch.  To push to the upstream branch
on the remote, use
git push REMOTE HEAD:REMOTE_BRANCH

To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use
git push REMOTE HEAD

To avoid automatically configuring an upstream branch when its name
won't match the local branch, see option 'simple' of branch.autoSetupMerge
in 'git help config'.`

If you checked out the pr with gh pr checkout, the upstream branch name should match. Not sure why it doesn't in your case. In my example here, after running that gh pr checkout command, my local branch is named test_registry_v3.

I'm using GitHub desktop which names the local branch pr/2103 as opposed to the branch name on the remote (i.e. on the contributor's fork).

Right, this solution was specifically for using the gh cli. If you're using something else, the solution will be different.

I'm not using the gh cli, but this is still a useful answer! Thank you.

@RaineRevere that message should probably also tell you about push.default, for dealing with upstream branches that don't match the name you use you want git config push.default upstream to make a no-args git push push your checked out branch to whatever it's tracking, regardless of name. The factory-default push.default setting is, as its docs will tell you, simple: refuse to default-push a branch upstream if the names don't match.  When the push.default is upstream that gh push will work correctly.

@jthill That's very helpful, thank you! I didn't see anything in the error message about push.default, but maybe I missed it. I think it pointed me towards branch.autoSetupMerge which did not seem relevant.

simplify the alias by using Git's@{u} syntax directly for the upstream branch
"  alias forcepr="git push @{u} --force"   "
pushes the current branch to its tracked upstream branch with force eliminating the need for cutting and parsing

I get an error: fatal: '@{u}' does not appear to be a git repository
